# How to set OnSeekBarChangedListener for SeekBar used in AlertDialog via LayoutInflater

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to access a SeekBar in a AlertDialog. 
I need to either setOnSeekBarChangeListener(), or access the SeekBar.getProgress() to get its value. Where do I do this? Is it possible?

The dialog is shown using showDialog(id) from onOptionsItemSelected.

The following code is used in onCreateDialog to create the AlertDialog with custom content which includes a SeekBar.

```
case CALIBRATE_DIALOG_ID: {
            // This example shows how to add a custom layout to an AlertDialog
            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            final View calibrateView = factory.inflate(R.layout.dlg_calibrate, null);
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                .setTitle("Calibrate")
                .setView(calibrateView)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        //mSeekBar1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.SeekBar01);
                        //Toast.makeText(ctx, mSeekBar1.getProgress(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        /* User clicked cancel so do some stuff */
                    }
                })
                .create();
        }
```

I can't do it in the main activity onCreate; the SeekBar has not been created yet. I thought I would be able to get a handle on the SeekBar.getProgress() value in the Ok Button's onClick handler but could not.

Any suggestions would be great!

thanks

patrick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get your `SeekBar` by calling `findViewById()` on your `calibrateView`, presumably.